# ValueError: Enum ErrorCode has no value defined for name '403' in mlflow.set_experiment()

Tags: python, mlflow, databricks-connect

I am trying to run some code to train a model, while logging my results to MLflow on Databricks. I keep getting the following error when I try to make a call to `mlflow.set_experiment()`,

```
    raise ValueError('Enum {} has no value defined for name {!r}'.format(
ValueError: Enum ErrorCode has no value defined for name '403'
```

What exactly is going on here?

I am using Databricks Connect to run my code and the section where the error pops up looks like this,

```
    # set remote tracking server URI
    mlflow.set_tracking_uri(remote_server_uri)

    # create the MLflow client
    client = MlflowClient(remote_server_uri)

    # set experiment to log mlflow runs
    mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the reason I was not able to log my experiments to MLflow is because I have missed the configuration steps that need to be performed before this can be achieved.

The document given below is a good guide on what needs to be done,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/applications/mlflow/access-hosted-tracking-server

In essence, the following steps must be performed when trying to access the MLflow tracking server from outside of Databricks,

1. Configure your environment to access your Azure Databricks hosted
   MLflow tracking server
2. Configure MLflow applications to log to Databricks
3. Configure the MLflow CLI